# Java maximum heap size on SGE cluster

Tags: java, python, cluster-computing

I have a pipeline written in python calling some processes in Java. The pipeline runs with two possible modes, on local mode (on a single node) or on SGE cluster.

When I set the option to cluster mode, the error message in the logs are such this

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g -jar
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

In local mode, there is no error and no problems.

My question is what can cause such an error ?

My class to run jobs either locally or on cluster is as follow

```
class LocalJobManager(JobManager):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmd_strs = []

    def add_job(self, cmd, cmd_args, **kwargs):
        cmd_str = ' '.join([cmd, ] + [str(x) for x in cmd_args])

        self.cmd_strs.append(cmd_str)

    def run_job(self, cmd, cmd_args, **kwargs):
        cmd_str = ' '.join([cmd, ] + [str(x) for x in cmd_args])

        self._run_cmd(cmd_str)

    def wait(self):
        for cmd_str in self.cmd_strs:
            self._run_cmd(cmd_str)

    def _run_cmd(self, cmd_str):
        '''
        Throw exception if run command fails
        '''
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_str, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

        process.stdin.close()

        sts = os.waitpid(process.pid, 0)

        if sts[1] != 0:
            raise Exception('Failed to run {0}\n'.format(cmd_str))

class ClusterJobManager(JobManager):
    def __init__(self, log_dir=None):
        import drmaa

        self._drmaa = drmaa

        self.log_dir = log_dir

        if self.log_dir is not None:
            make_directory(self.log_dir)

        self.session = self._drmaa.Session()

        self.session.initialize()

        self.job_ids = Queue()

        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def add_job(self, cmd, cmd_args, mem=4, max_mem=10, num_cpus=1):
        job_id = self._run_job(cmd, cmd_args, mem, max_mem, num_cpus)

        self.job_ids.put(job_id)

    def run_job(self, cmd, cmd_args, mem=4, max_mem=10, num_cpus=1):
        job_id = self._run_job(cmd, cmd_args, mem, max_mem, num_cpus)

        self._check_exit_status(job_id)

    def wait(self):
        self._lock.acquire()

        job_ids = []

        while not self.job_ids.empty():
            job_ids.append(self.job_ids.get())

        self.session.synchronize(job_ids, self._drmaa.Session.TIMEOUT_WAIT_FOREVER, False)

        self._lock.release()

        for job_id in job_ids:
            self._check_exit_status(job_id)

    def close(self):
        self.session.control(self._drmaa.Session.JOB_IDS_SESSION_ALL, self._drmaa.JobControlAction.TERMINATE)

        self.session.exit()

    def _run_job(self, cmd, cmd_args, mem, max_mem, num_cpus):
        job_template = self._init_job_template(cmd, cmd_args, mem, max_mem, num_cpus)

        job_id = self.session.runJob(job_template)

        self.session.deleteJobTemplate(job_template)

        return job_id

    def _init_job_template(self, cmd, cmd_args, mem, max_mem, num_cpus):
        job_template = self.session.createJobTemplate()

        job_template.remoteCommand = cmd

        job_template.args = [str(x) for x in cmd_args]

        job_template.workingDirectory = os.getcwd()

        if self.log_dir is not None:
            job_template.errorPath = ':' + self.log_dir

            job_template.outputPath = ':' + self.log_dir

        job_template.nativeSpecification = '-l mem_free={mem}G,mem_token={mem}G,h_vmem={max_mem}G -V -w n -pe ncpus {num_cpus}'.format(**locals())

        return job_template

    def _check_exit_status(self, job_id):
        return_value = self.session.wait(job_id, self._drmaa.Session.TIMEOUT_WAIT_FOREVER)

        if return_value.exitStatus != 0:
            raise Exception('Job {0} failed with exit status {1}.'.format(return_value.jobId,
                                                                          return_value.exitStatus))
```

Usually the Could not create the Java Virtual Machine (as I am reading though some forum) is caused by syntax error, even though the command called is correct and works locally, **besides the class to run jobs on the cluster show above, runs for everything except Java**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this on SGE. You may have a default hard memory limit set around 4GB and Java seems to use a bit more than that 4GB you are setting in the -Xmx4g parameter during initialization. Can you see if you administrator has set a hard memory limit? Typically you will set or override the default limit using:

```
qsub -l h_vmem=16G
```

Try giving far more memory than needed via that parameter and see if that solves it and then ratchet down the h_vmem as far down as it goes without crashing.

Comment: @Dar Be sure to click the accept arrow under the answer votes if this answers your question.

Comment: @Nit done ! I was just waiting for some minutes seq3 was fast :) thanks guys